# How to inject Values into a Null Object Using @Autowired in Spring IOC?

Tags: spring, dependency-injection, nullpointerexception, autowired

I just started working on a Spring Rest Application, currently I am managing the authentication operations, what I want to do is to Simply check if the typed email address is already used, the problem is that when It doesn't exist I can't autowire the bean **User** I get a NullPointerException.

I found similar questions in SOF but my code seems to be correct, please Help.

Here is My Code :

Project Architecture

[image]

**User.java:**

```
@Component
@Entity
@JsonIdentityInfo(generator=ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, property="idUser", scope = User.class)
public class User implements Serializable{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long idUser;
    @Column(name = "login", unique = true)
    private String login;
    private String password;
    private String nom;
    private String prenom;
    private String email;
    private long telephone;
    private String statut;
    private int isDeleted;

    @JsonIgnoreProperties({"hibernateLazyInitializer", "handler"})
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Role userRole;

    public User(Long idUser, String login, String password, String nom, String prenom, String email,
            long telephone, String statut, int isDeleted, Role userRole) {
        super();
        this.idUser = idUser;
        this.login = login;
        this.password = password;
        this.nom = nom;
        this.prenom = prenom;
        this.email = email;
        this.telephone = telephone;
        this.statut = statut;
        this.isDeleted = isDeleted;
        this.userRole = userRole;
    }

    public User() {
        super();
    }

    public Long getIdUser() {
        return idUser;
    }

    public void setIdUser(Long idUser) {
        this.idUser = idUser;
    }

    public String getLogin() {
        return login;
    }

    public void setLogin(String login) {
        this.login = login;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public String getNom() {
        return nom;
    }

    public void setNom(String nom) {
        this.nom = nom;
    }

    public String getPrenom() {
        return prenom;
    }

    public void setPrenom(String prenom) {
        this.prenom = prenom;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public long getTelephone() {
        return telephone;
    }

    public void setTelephone(long telephone) {
        this.telephone = telephone;
    }

    public String getStatut() {
        return statut;
    }

    public void setStatut(String statut) {
        this.statut = statut;
    }

    public int getIsDeleted() {
        return isDeleted;
    }

    public void setIsDeleted(int isDeleted) {
        this.isDeleted = isDeleted;
    }

    public Role getUserRole() {
        return userRole;
    }

    public void setUserRole(Role userRole) {
        this.userRole = userRole;
    }}
```

**UserRepository.java:**

```
@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {

    User findByLoginLikeAndPasswordLikeAndIsDeletedEquals(String login, String password, int i);

    User findByLoginLike(String login);
    }
```

**UserDTO.java**

```
@Component
public class UserDTO {

    private Long idUser;

    private String login;
    private String password;

    private String role ;

    public UserDTO(Long idUser, String login, String password, String role) {
        super();
        this.idUser = idUser;
        this.login = login;
        this.password = password;
        this.role = role;
    }

    public UserDTO() {
        super();
    }

    public Long getIdUser() {
        return idUser;
    }

    public void setIdUser(Long idUser) {
        this.idUser = idUser;
    }

    public String getLogin() {
        return login;
    }

    public void setLogin(String login) {
        this.login = login;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public String getRole() {
        return role;
    }

    public void setRole(String role) {
        this.role = role;
    } 

}
```

**UserService.java :**

```
@Service
public class UserService {


    @Autowired
    private UserDTO userDto;

    @Autowired
    private User user;


    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRep;

    @Autowired
    private RoleRepository roleRep;




    public boolean addUser(String login, String password, String role) {
        boolean state = false;


        try {
            System.out.println(user.toString());
            user = userRep.findByLoginLike(login);

            if (user == null) {

                user.setPassword(password);
                user.setLogin(login);               
                user.setUserRole(roleRep.findByNomRoleLike(role));
                userRep.save(user);

                state = true;

            } else {
                System.out.println("user already exists");
                state = false;
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
            state = false;
        }

        return state;
    }
```

**UserController.java**

```
@RestController
public class UserControler {



    @Autowired
    private User user;

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRep;

    @Autowired
    private List<User> allUsers;


    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @Autowired
    private UserDTO userDTO;


    @RequestMapping( value = "/addUser", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public Boolean addUser(@RequestBody UserDTO u){
        boolean state = false;
        try {
            state = userService.addUser(u.getLogin(), u.getPassword(), "Administrateur");
        } catch (Exception e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return state;
    }
```

**StackTrace :**

> Hibernate: select users0_.user_role_id_role as user_ro10_1_0_,
>   users0_.id_user as id_user1_1_0_, users0_.id_user as id_user1_1_1_,
>   users0_.email as email2_1_1_, users0_.is_deleted as is_delet3_1_1_,
>   users0_.login as login4_1_1_, users0_.nom as nom5_1_1_,
>   users0_.password as password6_1_1_, users0_.prenom as prenom7_1_1_,
>   users0_.statut as statut8_1_1_, users0_.telephone as telephon9_1_1_,
>   users0_.user_role_id_role as user_ro10_1_1_ from user users0_ where
>   users0_.user_role_id_role=? 2018-12-20 14:25:58.061 TRACE 6192 ---
>   [nio-8080-exec-5] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding
>   parameter [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jjLCP.png) as [BIGINT] - [3] 2018-12-20 14:26:36.015  WARN 6192 ---
>   [nio-8080-exec-7] .w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved
>   exception caused by handler execution:
>   org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException:
>   Request method 'POST' not supported
>
> **java.lang.NullPointerException  at**
>
> com.akkaprofil.service.UserService.addUser(UserService.java:63)   at
>   com.akkaprofil.controller.UserControler.addUser(UserControler.java:46)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:133)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:97)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:849)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:760)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:967)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:901)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:872)
>     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:661)     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
>     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:109)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:93)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:493)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:800)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:806)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1498)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
>     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
>     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

When I call the AddUser Request method, this Exception is triggered, I can't find the reason why values are not set to the user Object when the email adress is not found, All the classes are annotated woth their Stereotypes, the **user** 
 Bean is autowired, I haven't declared a new Operator.

Would you clarify the cause behind this Exception.
Thank you

Comment: Why on earth would your `User` and `UserDTO` need to be spring managed. Don't nothings like that. Next to that your code is dangerous and won't work in a situation you have multiple users.

Comment: `user` and `userDTO`  should be (dynamic) parameter to method and not `Autowired`

Comment: @M.Deinum The reason is because the front end developper wants to add the user only with the email address and password at first.

Comment: Still your `User` and `UserDTO` shouldn't be spring managed nor should they be kept at the service level. Your code simply won't work correctly in a concurrent environment.

Comment: @user7294900 cna you be more specific about how to make them dynamic ? is their an API or a framework to use?

Comment: @M.Deinum would you clarify how to dynamically manage user and userDTO ?

Comment: I was just about to write the same thing as @user7294900 . 
In Spring, or any other IOC, you have Injectables and Newables. Injectables are service, repositories, components. Newables are objects that you create new instances of them by either using keyword new or use some sort of factories, builders etc. You are mixing two concepts here. User and UserDTO is a Newable, meaning you should not annotate it with @ Component (since it's not).